# I am getting invalid sheetnames from Excel files using OleDb. What's wrong?

Tags: c#, oledb

I try to get excel sheet names, with oledb.

My connection string is:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
filepath + 
";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

where `filepath` is a filename.

My code for this:

```
List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>();
_excel.Connect(_path);
DataTable dataTable = _excel.ExecuteSchema();
_excel.Disconnect();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string sheetName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    if(!sheetName.EndsWith("$'")) { continue; }
    sheetNames.Add(sheetName);
 }
```

the list with the sheets names contains all valid sheet names and some other sheet names.
Example:

- `"'correctsheetname$'"`
- `"'correctsheetname$'Print_Area"`

I only add sheets that end in `$'`

My problem is that if a sheet name contains a single quote, I get it with two single quotes.

Example: 
 for sheet named `asheetname's` I get `'asheetname''s$''`

Afterwards, when I try to get the datasource of this sheet, I am getting an exception that this sheet doesn't exist.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ['asheetname''s$']"
_command = new OleDbCommand(query, _connection);
_dataTable = new DataTable();
_dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();   <-- Exception is thrown here
```

And the exception message:

`{System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ''asheetname''s$'' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at PrestaImporter.Entity.Excel.ExecuteQuery(String query)`

Comment: Use a method to determine if the name contains quotes and then extract the extra quote out of the name.

Comment: Are there any other characters that should be replaced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
"SELECT * FROM [" + asheetname + "$]"
```

if it won't, try manually typing the sheet name into the string variable asheetname - it should open.

```
"SELECT * FROM ["SHEET_NAME"$]"
```

Comment: //Cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [sheet1$]";  //Does not work    but the following works for me, my sheet name is "Regular People"
            Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + "Regular  People" + "$]";

Answer (score 0):

Use a sheet name that does not contain spaces ..
ex. my sheet : it's bad choice ..
mysheet  : it works